# A limited composition of two unlimited functions on natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, puzzle

Can someone give an example of two functions $f,g:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ such that 
$|\operatorname{Im}f|,|\operatorname{Im}\,g|\notin\Bbb N$, but such that 
$|\operatorname{Im}\,g\circ f|\in\Bbb N$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
f(n)=2n+1
$$
$$
g(n) = \begin{cases}
1 \quad \mbox{if $n$ is odd}; \\
n \quad \mbox{if $n$ is even}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Yeah! :) Not my best!